# Getting error for `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command on my gcloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-shell

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.print-identity-token) No identity token can be obtained from the current credentials.
```

On `gcloud auth list`, I can see my account as active account(user account).
I am trying this on cloud shell.
Note - This was working earlier, I was able to generate the JWT Token from this command.

Comment: Try restarting the Cloud Shell instance (VM).

Comment: Already tried. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already reported in this [PIT thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/168705031) and you can track and follow up here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Kumar Shaswat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6514611/kumar-shaswat),

Today I have tried this again with `Google Cloud SDK 310.0.0` and found in [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) I can run the command`$ gcloud auth print-identity-token`.

Thus requesting you to check the `$ gcloud version` and retry it.

Comment: Also the [PIT](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/168705031) ensure this issue is fixed now